# Calling module constant?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following Angular module. How can i call for example APIHost from one of my controllers?

```
angular.module('configuration', [])
    .constant('APIHost','http://api.com')
    .constant('HostUrl','http://example.com')
    .constant('SolutionName', 'MySite');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constant is nothing but one kind of provider recipe.

You need to inject `constant` dependency inside your `controller` factory function, that's it.

```
app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope, APIHost){
  console.log(APIHost)
})
```

> Make sure your `configuration` module has been added to main module as dependency
>   to get use of `constant`'s provider like below

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['configuration', 'otherdependency']);
app.controller( ... ) //here you can have configuration constant available
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this, just like any service or factory.

I have also include structure for industry standard (kind of) from [john papa's coding guidelines](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide).

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('configuration')
        .controller('ctrlXYZ', ctrlXYZ);
    //Just inject as you would inject a service or factory
    ctrlXYZ.$inject = ['APIHost'];

    /* @ngInject */
    function ctrlXYZ(APIHost) {
        var vm = this;

        activate();

        function activate() {
            //Go crazy with APIHost
            console.log(APIHost);
        }
    }
})();
```

Hope the helps!